# Select is not updating after on change

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

I'm using `Nuxt.js` with `Buefy` and have a `select dropdown` with options. I have reactivity using `v-model` and `@input.native="options(selectedOptions.windowsLicence)"`, however I'm now trying to add the data to an order object. So it's showing the last selection value on change, rather than it's updated one, even though my v-model gets updated.

Do I need to put a watcher on this or can I somehow do it within a computed method?

**Methods**

```
       options(val){
            let selectedOption = {
                id:'54',
                title: this.selectedOptions.windowsLicence.label,
                price: this.selectedOptions.windowsLicence.price
            }
            this.order.windowsLicence = selectedOption;
        },
```

**Dropdown**

```
 <b-field class="pt-3">
    <b-select 
       placeholder="None - $0.00"
       expanded
       @input.native="options(selectedOptions.windowsLicence)"
       v-model="selectedOptions.windowsLicence"
       icon="windows"
       icon-pack="fab"
       size="is-medium">
       <optgroup>
            <option v-for="(licence, key, index) in serverOptions.windowsLicences" :key="index" :value="{ 'id':licence.id, 'label':licence.label, 'price':licence.price }">{{licence.label}} - ${{licence.price}}.00</option>
        </optgroup>
     </b-select>
 </b-field>
```

**Data Property - Has Reactivity**

```
{{selectedOptions.windowsLicence}}
```

**Adding to the order is 1 step behind in the selection**

```
{{order}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-model` is a shortcut for adding both `@input` and `:value` in one directive.

Docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components.

Adding `.native` to an event handler means listening to actual DOM element event not Vue component event.

`<b-select />` renders a `<div>` which doesn't have an `input` event.

Say you are interested if `<b-select />` is clicked.

`<b-select />` does not `$emit('click')` event so you cannot do `@click="doSomethingWhenClicked"`

that's when you use `<b-select @click.native="doSomethingWhenClicked" />`

---

To answer how you can react to value selected,

you can either do watcher or methods.

Watcher

```html
<template>
  <b-select v-model="selected" />
</template>

<script>
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null
    }
  },

  watch: {
    selected(newValue, oldValue) {
      // Do something here
    }
  }
</script>
```

Methods

```html
<template>
  <b-select :value="selected" @input="onSelect" />
</template>

<script>
  ...
  data() {
    return {
      selected: null
    }
  },

  methods: {
    onSelect(selectedValue) {
      this.selected = selectedValue
      // Do something here
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Strange to rely on `native` at all since it looks like it emits the proper thing: https://buefy.org/documentation/select#api-view